# Read and write keywords in image in Photos library

Tags: ios, swift, image, metadata, exif

I need to be able to read and write the keywords associated with a photo in the Photos app library. It's possible to do it on Mac, you can set keywords for specific photos and you can read them on the Photos app. How can I do the same in Swift on iOS? I've already tried to extract metadata, but with no success for the keywords.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution here? I'm hunting for the same exact thing for my app.

Comment: Nothing. Based on what I know, it's not possible to do this.